# Manipulate values in a JSON in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, manipulate

I am new to Nodejs and JSON manipulations.  I have a jSON that looks like

```
"ent": [
        {
            "employee": [
                {
                    "emp_name": "",
                    "column": "employee",
                    "emp_id": 123456,
                    "first name": "Joe",
                    "last name": "Bloggs",
                    "email": "",
                    "ldapid":
                } ,
                 {
                    "emp_name": "",
                    "column": "employee",
                    "emp_id": 123456,
                    "first name": "Foo",
                    "last name": "Bars",
                    "email": "",
                    "ldapid":
                }
                
            ]
        }
        
        ]
```

I need to fill the email, ldapid and emp_name based on the firstname and last name

The desired output is

```
"ent": [
        {
            "employee": [
                {
                    "emp_name": "Joe Bloggs",
                    "column": "employee",
                    "emp_id": 123456,
                    "first name": "Joe",
                    "last name": "Bloggs",
                    "email": "jbloggs@mycompemail.com",
                    "ldapid": "jbloggs"
                } ,
                 {
                    "emp_name": "Foo Bars",
                    "column": "employee",
                    "emp_id": 567891,
                    "first name": "Foo",
                    "last name": "Bars",
                    "email": "fbars@mycompemail.com",
                    "ldapid": "fbars"
                }
                
            ]
        }
        
        ]
```

Since I am super new to the nodeJS world , I am making some initial steps to get to where I want..

The following is what I have done..

EDITED my POST

Hi All, Thanks for all your responses.
I was hoping to get an answer that did something similar to the below. this may not be a code with best practices, but does what I want, may be experts in this group can make it better.

```
const fs = require('fs');

/** Method to start  
 * 
 *  
 */
const main = async () => {

    const myJSONObject = require('./people.json');
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.entities.length; i++) {
            var entity = myJSONObject.entities[i];

            if (entity.People) {
                for (var j = 0; j < entity.People.length; j++) {
                    var people = entity.People[j];
                    var fn = people["first name"];
                    var ln = people["last name"];
                    var email = `${fn.substring(0, 3)}${ln.substring(0, 5)}@mycompmail.com`;
                    var ldapid = `${fn.substring(0, 3)}${ln.substring(0, 5)}`;

                
                    myJSONObject.entities[i].People[j]["email"] = email.toLowerCase();
                    myJSONObject.entities[i].People[j]["ldap id"] = ldapid.toLowerCase();
                    myJSONObject.entities[i].People[j]["preferred first name"] = fn;
                    myJSONObject.entities[i].People[j]["preferred last name"] = ln;
                   
                    //  console.log(`${fn}.${ln}`)

                }

            }

        }
        fs.writeFileSync('./new_people.json', JSON.stringify(myJSONObject, 0, 4));
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

};

(async () => {
    await main();
})();
```

Any help in this is highly appreciated.
Vakichak

Comment: Hm, have you tried something? Show us your code, please. We are not free-freelancers xD

Comment: What is your problem? Finding the correct element to update? Calculating the correct email address / id? Setting the values?

Comment: My problem is iterating through each of the employee object.. Once in the employee object , I am fine to do the rest. I started to write my code 

    const myJSONObject = require('./people.json');
   
    for(const i = 0; i < myJSONObject.entities.length; i++)
{
    const entity = myJSONObject.entities[i];
     
   // I know here that I have the first employee obj..
//  I need to iterate through the children and get manipulate
    // I need to then create a new JSON output which has the changed values
}

Comment: I edited my original post to show what I have done

Comment: so...  `ent` (or `entities`?) is an array in which an item (or more?) may have the form `{employee: [{object},{object} ]}` (therefore employee is an array of employees?)

Answer (score 0):

From your code snipped I assume, that the JSON is a string in a file.

So the first step you need to do is to import the file contents into a variable. You can do that with [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Now you have the string in a variable.

Next you need to do is to convert the string into an object. You can do that with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Now you have an object that you can manipulate.

To write it the object back into a file, you can use `JSON.stringify()` to make it a string again and then `fs.writeFileSync()` to write it to the file.

Full script:

```js
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync('./people.json')
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)

// do stuff with jsonObject that is written into newJsonObject

const newJsonString = JSON.stringify(newJsonObject)
fs.writeFileSync('./new_people.json', newJsonObject)
```

Note: there's also async functions for writing and reading files. The sync functions are okay if you load a config or something like this at the beginning of a script. If you read/write many files during runtime, you should use the async functions.